# How to combine EF and ADO?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, ado

After reading forums and articles, I found that using the `Entity Framework`
you can quickly create a database, and ADO can be used to conventional SQL queries and get accurate results. Also there are many questions all over the internet: what is better, ADO or EF? And in responses saying that need to combine these two technologies, each in its own good. But here's the question of how combine these two technologies and use them in the same project?

For example, i have several tables that mapped to entites, like `employee` and `tasks`. With EF i can create new `employees` and add them to database. But what if i want to create a report, that can be easely created with complex `SQL` query from many tables. The result of this `SQL` query can't match existing entities, so what to do? Create new entity-model to match this report and create this `LINQ` query to build it, or use ADO and `SQL` query?

Comment: You can generate complex type from the output of the stored procedure. Plus you can definitely use the sql with ADO.Net and use your model instead of entity framework

Answer (score 1):

**EF** actually use **ADO** deep inside itself.

If you want to execute plain SQL in EF you can use theese methods:

```
SqlQuery()  //for selects

ExecuteSqlCommand() //for Delete, Insert, Update
```

Check [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592907(v=vs.113).aspx).

Comment: Yes, i can use SQL query in EF, but how to store that data? How to bind it with MVVM pattern for example?

Comment: @NickolayKabash your question is too broad without code. Acually you bind it like you bind any other model. If you have ViewModel that differs with your DBModel - write mapper.